# how to upload images without reloading page in modx revolution

Tags: image, modx, modx-revolution

How to upload images in web context (frontend) without reloading the page in modx revolution? I am trying to use `fileupload` extra for uploading images but it is reloading the page. Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i got the answer. we can do it without using FILEUPLOAD addon by using the simple php code and a small javascript..
php code:-

```
<?php

$path = "uploads/";

$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp","jpeg");
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
$name = $_FILES['photoimg']['name'];
$size = $_FILES['photoimg']['size'];
if(strlen($name))
{
list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))
{
if($size<(1024*1024)) // Image size max 1 MB
{
$actual_image_name = time().".".$ext;
$tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];
if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name))
{

echo "image uploaded";
}
else
echo "failed";
}
else
echo "Image file size max 1 MB";
}
else
echo "Invalid file format..";
}
else
echo "Please select image..!";
exit;
}
```

for other javascript and all u can refer the below link:-
http://www.9lessons.info/2011/08/ajax-image-upload-without-refreshing.html